# Apply css style to dynamic div ID?

Tags: wordpress, css

Is there a way to apply CSS styles to dynamically generated divs?

In this case, In Wordpress, I have a div class of .profiles and dynamically generated div ID's within that class of #profile-1, 2, 3 etc.

What I want to do, is apply the same styling to each profile-1, 2 etc div id's without having to specify the styling in each and every one within the stylesheet.

Is this possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: Any specific reason why not generate the divs with a classname instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may not be fully understanding the question, but couldn't you just create a style for the class .profiles in your css? If all of your divs use that class, then it should work just fine.

```
.profiles { (put your style here) }
```

Comment: +1 for the correct solution. Instead of breaking your head giving IDs to multiple, similar elements, use the same classname, which is its purpose in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in your css:

`div[id^="profile-"] { your styles }`

Answer (score 0):

If the only childs inside `<div class="profiles">` are your targeted divs, you can style them all this way:

```
.profiles div {
    /*your style here*/
}
```

Another way to address this problem would be to add a class to all of your divs (and then style that class). In Wordpress, you can do that easily in the template files.